# How to get multiple input and select into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<form action="">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>one</th>
            <th>two</th>
            <th>three</th>
            <th>four</th>
            <th>five</th>
            <th>six</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select>
                <option value="1">one</option>
                <option value="2">two</option>
                <option value="3">three</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" id="check" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="2" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="3" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="4" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="5" /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <button id="onSubmit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

> I want to get the value of input something like this using jquery or javascript

```js
const data = [{one:"option1" two:"input1" three:"input2" four:"input3" five: "input4" six: "input5"}]
```

I want the whole process dynamic so when I add a similar row then get

```js
const data = [
  {one:"option1" two:"input1" three:"input2" four:"input3" five: "input4" six: "input5"},
  {one:"option1" two:"input1" three:"input2" four:"input3" five: "input4" six: "input5"}
]
```

Comment: What is you expected output?

Comment: Can you translate `one:"option1"` and how does it refers to your actual HTML? Where did you got that `"one"` object property name from? `"option1"` means... the... option value? And just out of curiosity (since I think you're doing something odd here) what will be that data than used for?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the select value and all the number values for every row, you could map-reduce the table rows and reduce their cells into an object like so:

```js
const getRowData = (table) => {
  const fields = [...table.querySelectorAll('thead tr th')]
    .map(td => td.textContent);

  return [...table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')].map(tr =>
    [... tr.querySelectorAll('td')].reduce((acc, td, index) => {
      const
        select = td.querySelector('select'),
        number = td.querySelector('input[type="number"]'),
        key = fields[index];
      let value = null;

      if      (select) value = select.value;
      else if (number) value = number.value;

      return { ...acc, [key]: value };
  }, {}))
}
  

console.log(getRowData(document.querySelector('table')));
```

```css
.record { background: yellow; }
.record input, .record select { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<form action="">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
        <th>three</th>
        <th>four</th>
        <th>five</th>
        <th>six</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="record">
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" id="check" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="3" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="5" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="record">
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" id="check" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="3" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="5" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button id="onSubmit">submit</button>
</form>
```

### Result

```json
[
  {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "",
    "three": "2",
    "four": "3",
    "five": "4",
    "six": "5"
  },
  {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "",
    "three": "2",
    "four": "3",
    "five": "4",
    "six": "5"
  }
]
```

You can simply the code above into the following:

```js
const getRowData = (table) =>
  (fields =>
    [...table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')].map(tr =>
      [... tr.querySelectorAll('td')].reduce((acc, td, index) =>
        ({
          ...acc,
          [fields[index]]: td.querySelector('select, input[type="number"]').value
        }), {})))
  ([...table.querySelectorAll('thead th')].map(td => td.textContent));
  

console.log(getRowData(document.querySelector('table')));
```

```css
.record { background: yellow; }
.record input, .record select { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<form action="">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
        <th>three</th>
        <th>four</th>
        <th>five</th>
        <th>six</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="record">
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" id="check" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="3" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="5" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="record">
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" id="check" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="3" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="5" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button id="onSubmit">submit</button>
</form>
```